# Append dictionary to pandas dataframe from a specific index number

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, data-science

I have 2 columns in a Pandas DataFrame and a dictionary generator function which takes the input from the dataframe rolling indexes and gives output as a dictionary and then it should add the keys as column and values as rows to the existing pandas dataframe from a specific index. The sample DataFrame is:

```
+-------+---+---+
| Index | A | B |
+-------+---+---+
|     0 | 2 | 4 |
|     1 | 5 | 6 |
|     2 | 1 | 7 |
|     3 | 4 | 6 |
|     4 | 2 | 7 |
|     5 | 8 | 4 |
|     6 | 3 | 1 |
|     7 | 8 | 2 |
+-------+---+---+
```

The code which takes the input rows(window) from dataframe is below:

```py
def stack(df, window=3):
    for i in range(0, df.shape[0] - window):
        dfp = df[i:i+window]
        mp = addition(dfp) #a dict generator function to add 3 previous values of column a and b and give output with a single dict {'C': value, 'D': value}
        for key, value in mp.items():      # to assign keys as column and values as rows
            df.loc['i+window', key] = value   # to assign rows from a specific index -3
    return df
```

The for-loop function produces 1 dictionary with each loop which look like this :

```py
{'C': 8, 'D': 17}  #1st loop
{'C': 10, 'D': 19} #2nd loop
{'C': 7, 'D': 20}  #3rd loop
{'C': 14, 'D': 17} #4th loop
{'C': 13, 'D': 12} #5th loop
```

But there is an error in output while applying the above slower function makes every row values to NaN except the last one. I want the The expected output should be added to the dataframe row by row with every loop and the final dataframe should look like below:

```
+-------+---+---+-----+-----+
| Index | A | B |  C  |  D  |
+-------+---+---+-----+-----+
|     0 | 2 | 4 | NaN | NaN |
|     1 | 5 | 6 | NaN | NaN |
|     2 | 1 | 7 | 8    | 17 |
|     3 | 4 | 6 | 10   | 19   |
|     4 | 2 | 7 | 7   | 20  |
|     5 | 8 | 4 | 14   | 17   |
|     6 | 3 | 1 | 13   | 12  |
+-------+---+---+-----+-----+
```

Besides the above expected output I also want to make the looping as faster as possible. Please make me understand where i an going wrong and pardon me for my bad english..

Comment: `df.rolling(window).sum()`?

Comment: No problem with the addition function it is just an example, but my problem with looping of dictionary keys and values to the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Another option instead of looping:

```
df.combine_first(pd.DataFrame(dd_list, index=range(window,len(dd_list)+window)))
```

Updating with what I think you are asking as far as adding a dictionary to a dataframe:

```
dd_list = [{'C': 8, 'D': 17},  #1st loop
{'C': 10, 'D': 19}, #2nd loop
{'C': 7, 'D': 20},  #3rd loop
{'C': 14, 'D': 17}, #4th loop
{'C': 13, 'D': 12}, ]

window = 2
for n, i in enumerate(dd_list):
    df = df.combine_first(pd.DataFrame(i, index=[n+window]))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B     C     D
0  2  4   NaN   NaN
1  5  6   NaN   NaN
2  1  7   8.0  17.0
3  4  6  10.0  19.0
4  2  7   7.0  20.0
5  8  4  14.0  17.0
6  3  1  13.0  12.0
7  8  2   NaN   NaN
```

---

As @QuangHoang was suggesting, to generate your output you can do this with method:

```
df.join(df.rolling(3).sum().rename(columns={'A':'C', 'B':'D'}))
```

Output:

```
       A  B     C     D
Index                  
0      2  4   NaN   NaN
1      5  6   NaN   NaN
2      1  7   8.0  17.0
3      4  6  10.0  19.0
4      2  7   7.0  20.0
5      8  4  14.0  17.0
6      3  1  13.0  12.0
7      8  2  19.0   7.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Although `df.combine_first` code is working but can you edit the code to also work with timestamp index and if any suggestion to make the looping faster.

Comment: @ScrappyCoco See another option.

Comment: I have a custom function which makes output as dictionary, so i am not able to combine it with the rolling function. But df.combine_first works fine except for timestamp index. Any suggestion will be helpful.@ScottBoston